# How to check quiet NaN in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, nan

I know if(value==value) does the trick but in my application I have more than 50 variables that I need to check and checking each is a bit tedious and probably inefficient. Ideally what I am looking for is before the  end of the subroutine I can call a function (if such a function exists) and it will return 1 or  0.I have a feeling since in assembly such a function  exist which can check the global floating point status register. 
If that's not the case then is there any better way than polling value==value for each floating point variable?

Comment: How can you end up with NaN in C ?

Comment: @Eregrith: `sqrt(-1)`, `log(-1)`, `0. / 0` etc.

Comment: Do you want to know whether *any* of them is a NaN? If so, maybe `isnan(var1 + var2 + var3 + ...)`. But don't take my word for that, first check whether it will generate false positives and if so whether they matter to you. For example maybe `+INF + -INF` is `NaN`, I don't remember. Btw, the real problem here is that you have 50 variables to check -- normally you would perform some calculation using several values, and only care whether the *result* is a NaN. The point of quiet NaN is that it propagates through. Some would even say 50 variables in any one function is immediately a mistake.

Comment: I know but I am updating some external vendor's firmware so nothing much I can do about it, however summing is a good idea; I will see how it goes.

Comment: Actually, `isnan` is a macro in C, isn't it? So if that wasn't already obvious to you: the exact expression I wrote is not good, it might evaluate the sum twice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`isnan`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Classes.html) or `fpclassify`. Both are standard in C99.

As to your problem, if your variables are all declared in some common place, I'd write a little tool to turn these declarations into a string of `isnan` calls.

Comment: Thanks but that does not solve my problem though. I still need to call isnan on all of my varables.

Comment: @AlexandreC. loop over all the `double` variables in a function? I suppose you could first create an array of pointers to them all, then loop over that. I think all three of us here have the same complaint, that 50 variables is Just Wrong, but that doesn't *necessarily* mean Arunav can fix that first before solving the immediate problem.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Indeed, a table of pointers is one horrible solution. Actually it depends quite on the existing implementation: it may be that Arunav can let the NaNs bubble up until they are actually used and can be checked.

One can also have the variables declared in some common place, and write a little parser which turns these declarations into a bunch of isnan calls.

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is no way to ask “Is there a NaN somewhere in my data?”

Checking the processor’s floating-point registers would be insufficient to answer this question, as the values of floating-point objects are held in memory as well as in registers at various points of the computation, especially if you have fifty of them.

There is a way to ask “Has an invalid operation exception occurred?” Clause 7.6 of the C standard specifies the floating-point environment access, via macros and functions defined in . Support for it may be poor in various compilers. Essentially, you would want to clear FE_INVALID with feclearexcept, perform some computations, and test whether FE_INVALID has been set with fetestexcept. You also need to set “#pragma STD FENV_ACESS on”.

This will only test for whether an invalid operation exception occurs during your computations. It will not test for whether a NaN exists in your input data. It will not test for a NaN that has been generated without an invalid operation exception.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this may help?

```
void registerAddVariable(double *x) {
  APPEND(x); // append to some global linked list
}
void registerRemoveVariable(double *x) {
  REMOVE(x); // remove from same global linked list
}
void registerDebug() {
  list = head; 
  while(list) {
    if (isnan(*(list->variable))) {
      output(list);
    }
    list = list->next;
  }
}

void myfun() {
  double variable; registerAddVariable(&variable);
  ...
  registerDebug();
  ....
  registerRemoveVariable(&variable);
}
```